# Android App that implements Facebook (SDK 4.0.1) Login

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, access-token

I want to implement an Android App (part of a Web App) that users can login using facebook (and later Twitter etc).

1. what values should i save in my database. My thought is email,password, provider, access_token
   email, password => in-app login
   provider, access_token => login from provider app
2. access_token can expire or change. How i track the changes. I could save it in SystemPreference but is a cached one not a new one. Do i need to perform a GraphRequest to check the validity every time

Answer (score 0):

> what values should i save in my database?

No.
You cannot save user's facebook credentials into your local database. Because Facebook SDK never allows that.

> access_token can expire or change

Yes it can expire or change.If the `access_token` expires and if the user tries to login using Facebook then it generates new one.So no need of caching things.

**EDIT**

Access tokens are two types :
*1.Short Lived* and *2.Long Lived*.

Long lived are used in mobile applications which is valid for 60 days and on the other hand short lived are only valid for few hours which is used by web applications,and if you wanted to extend your access token for web you can refer this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending)

Comment: 1. I need to save a kind of information in order to authenticate the user in my app through facebook. Based on OAuth protocol each access_token is private for my app and authenticates each user. Meaning, it s like a set of permission that user gives to my app and thus authenticate himself to me. 
So if a user sign up from my android app, and then sign in from browser the produced access_token is the same and i am going to recognize him.

Comment: so is it to recognize the same user both web and mobile ?

Comment: Yes, because my app (both android and web) must recognize the same user. Look i logged in many times and i found that the access_token is the same, if the permissions asked are the same. And based on OAuth, this is the lets say "credentials". But if expires or change the permission a new one is produced. And i dont know how to track it